# Python Flask webpage stalls as long as the POST request task

Tags: flask, post, freeze

In Python Flask I'm sending a POST request with some network tasks.
All works fine, but the Flask website stalls (freezes) as long as the task is working on it.
For example animated.gif also freezes as long as the task is lasting.
I tried app.run(threaded=True), but that doesn't change.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe you can consider running the app with `gunicorn` instead with multiple workers

Comment: `$ gunicorn --workers=2 test:app`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, setting theaded=True, only means that it will process multiple request but each request is still handled by a single thread. If you can't cut down on the processing time, you could try better ways for dealing with the long running task on the UI.